# What are the advantages/disadvantages of integration vs. summation?

Tags: integration, summation, intuition

If we are given a function, $f(x)$, we can either integrate it or sum it.  I'm wondering what integration can do with $f(x)$ that summation can't, and what summation can do that integration can't.

For example, we can make a list of what is easy for integration, and what is easy for summation:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Integration} & \text{Summation} \\
\hline
\frac{1}{f(x)} & \binom{x}{n} \\
f(x) \to f(ax+b) & \text{falling factorials} \\
\dots & \dots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

I'm wondering if someone can give us a general feel for what the pros and cons are of integration versus summation.  In other words, what functions are easier for one or the other?

Comment: What do you mean by "summing" a function?

Comment: By summing, I mean $\sum_x{f(x)}$.  It's studied in the difference calculus.

Comment: They are appropriate in different situations...

Comment: @vonbrand:  I was afraid of this - I guess my question is too broad.  I'm just trying to get a general feel, besides my own knowledge, of when one is easier than the other.

Comment: If you have a function defined on the integers, then you can do summation, but integration makes no sense. If you have a function defined on the reals, then you can do integration, but summation via $f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+\cdots$ will ignore all the function values in between. So it's apples and oranges over here. (Although we do have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) = \int_0^\infty f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\,\mathrm dx$, for what it's worth.)